# appdomain c++ c#

Tags: c#, load, appdomain

when we write 
Assembly asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(SomeByteArray);

when SomeByteArray read from .net .exe  all is ok, and when from c++, error.

for this  function is important using .net exe ?

if yes  please other way to do this.

thanks

Comment: When you say "C++" do you mean C++/CLI? What is the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: Could not load file or assembly '38400 bytes loaded from ConsoleApplication3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

ConsoleApplication3 is my program where i call  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(template) method, 

thanks

Comment: i think it is not possible:( 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(SomeByteArray);
SomeByteArray must be .net :(  , i am right?

Answer (score 0):

Are the calling assembly and the one you're loading both the same kind of build (x86, x64 or AnyCpu)?  You can check the build by looking at them in ILDASM (look at the manifest, scroll to bottom and look for corflags).

If you built both assemblies yourself, then just check the property pages of the project for how you built it.

You either have to make sure they are the same, or if the .exe is AnyCpu, then the assembly you are loading must match whatever the OS is.  Meaning it must be x86 on a 32-bit OS or x64 on a 64-bit OS.

(this is all assuming that SomeByteArray was loaded from the file correctly)